# Sporadic delivery failure to gmail accounts when using MS 365 Distribution Lists

Tags: gmail, distribution-lists, microsoft-365

Occasionally (I can't figure out any pattern when it works and when it doesn't), when a user (Mail Contact) on my org's MS 365 Distribution Lists sends an email to the list, email will not be delivered to (I believe) all the gmail.com addresses on the list. The sender receives a non-delivery notice about 2-3 days after the email is sent. This has only happened to users on the list outside of our org; users on my org's domain do not have this issue. This has happened to me (I have my own personal MS 365 tenant, from which I am sending to my org's distinct MS 365 tenant), as well as gmail users on the Distribution List. The problem manifests itself with multiple of my org's Distribution Lists.

Here is a sample of the non-delivery message (email address has been changed):

> **Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:**
>
> dahonig22@gmail.com
>  Your message couldn't be delivered. Despite
> repeated attempts to contact the recipient's email system it didn't
> respond.
>
> Contact the recipient by some other means (by phone, for example) and
> ask them to tell their email admin that it appears that their email
> system isn't accepting connection requests from your email system.
> Give them the error details shown below. It's likely that the
> recipient's email admin is the only one who can fix this problem.
>
> For more information and tips to fix this issue see this article:
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=389361.
>
> Diagnostic information for administrators:
>
> Generating server: PH0P221MB0733.NAMP221.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
> Receiving server: PH0P221MB0733.NAMP221.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 
>  Total
> retry attempts: 14
>
> dahonig22@gmail.com
>  1/21/2023 3:45:51 AM - Server at
> PH0P221MB0733.NAMP221.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM returned '550 5.4.300 Message
> expired -> 421 4.4.2 Connection dropped due to SocketError'
> 1/21/2023 3:39:02 AM - Server at gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
> (142.250.27.27) returned '421 4.4.2 Connection dropped due to
> SocketError'

This has been happening for close to a year now. Any suggestions as to how to resolve are much appreciated!